# Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@13a355b9 to flash.display.DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3

I get this error when running, no compile errors.

```
package  {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;

public class mainCode extends MovieClip{
    //global variables go here
    public var circled:Shape = new Shape();
    public var circled2:Shape = new Shape();
    public var circled3:Shape = new Shape();
    public var angled:int = new int();
    public var circlearray1:Array = new Array(4); 
    public var circlearray2:Array = new Array(4); 
    public function mainCode(){
        makeCircle(circled, 100);
        makeCircle(circled2, 50);
        makeCircle(circled3, 50);
        for(var i:int=0; i<4; i++){circlearray1[i] = new Array(20);}
        for(var n:int=0; n<4; n++){circlearray2[n] = new Array(20);}
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);

    }
    //functions go here
    private function mainLoop(e:Event){
        trace(1);
        angled+=1;
        angled%=360;
        circled.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        circled.y = stage.stageHeight/ 2;
        circled2.x = circled.x + 100*Math.cos(radians(angled));
        circled2.y = circled.y + 100*Math.sin(radians(angled));
        circled3.x = circled.x + 100*Math.cos(radians((angled + 180) % 360));
        circled3.y = circled.y + 100*Math.sin(radians((angled + 180) % 360));
        trace(2);
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            trace(3);
            if (circlearray1[i][0] != undefined) 
            {removeChild(circlearray1[i][0]);}
            if (circlearray2[i][0] != undefined) 
            {removeChild(circlearray2[i][0]);}
            trace(4);
            for (var m:int = 0; m < 19; m++)
            {
                circlearray1[i][m] = circlearray1[m+1];
                circlearray2[i][m] = circlearray2[m+1];
            }
            circlearray1[i][19] = new Shape();
            circlearray2[i][19] = new Shape();
            makeCircle(circlearray1[i][19], 25);
            makeCircle(circlearray2[i][19], 25);
            circlearray1[i][19].x = circled2.x + 50*Math.cos(radians(((-angled + (i*90)) * 2) % 360));
            circlearray1[i][19].y = circled2.y + 50*Math.sin(radians(((-angled + (i*90)) * 2) % 360));
            circlearray2[i][19].x = circled3.x + 50*Math.cos(radians(((-angled + (i*90)) * 2) % 360));
            circlearray2[i][19].y = circled3.y + 50*Math.sin(radians(((-angled + (i*90)) * 2) % 360));
            trace(8);
        }
    }
    private function makeCircle(circles:Shape, radius:int)
    {
        circles.graphics.clear();
        circles.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000);
        circles.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
        circles.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,radius);
        circles.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(circles);
    }
    private function degrees(radians:Number):Number
    {
        return radians * 180/Math.PI;
    }

    private function radians(degrees:Number):Number
    {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }
    private function killCircle(circlei:Shape):void {
        removeChild(circlei);
    }
}   
}
```

I've traced it down to {removeChild(circlearray1[i][0]);}, which seems to be returning the error. I have no idea why it's doing this, I've tried alternatives such as circlearray1[i][0].parent.removeChild(circlearray1[i][0]); and if (circlearray1[i][0] is Shape) ... , but no dice.

For reference, I'm trying to make some circles circle around other circles, but have the outermost circles leave an "image lag" (or afterimage) while moving. I do this by creating objects and deleting them using for loops and multidimensional arrays, as I dont feel like typing out 50 create object calls manually and edit each one manually.

Comment: How have you determined `removeChild(circlearray1[i][0]);` is the cause?

Comment: Try waiting to initialize your shapes until the constructor. I sometimes used to get these error when I'd have a library object that was instantiated not inside a method.     So instead of ` public var circled:Shape = new Shape();` just do ` public var circled:Shape;` then in your constructor (`mainCode`) instantiate the objects.  In AS3 it's best not instantiate any non-primatives in class definitions.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I determined it through traces, with a (now deleted) trace that traced in between the if statement and the removeChild.

I tried what you said with the moving the instantiator into the mainCode, but the error still occurs. I should note that the code does run, with the center circle being drawn and the 2 circles that orbit it also being drawn and do orbit around it, but the outer "4" circles that orbit those 2 circles do nothing, they remain/are created exactly where they were when the code was initialized.

Comment: Also not sure why I got downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this part:

```
        for (var m:int = 0; m < 19; m++)
        {
            circlearray1[i][m] = circlearray1[m+1];
            circlearray2[i][m] = circlearray2[m+1];
        }
```

You assign to endpoint elements, which you initially assume to be **Shape**s the elements which are **Array**s. Then later you go at **circlearray1[i][0]** assuming it is **Shape** if it is not empty, but it is already an **Array** due to the assignment above. It's probably a typo and you meant this:

```
        for (var m:int = 0; m < 19; m++)
        {
            circlearray1[i][m] = circlearray1[i][m+1];
            circlearray2[i][m] = circlearray2[i][m+1];
        }
```

There's actually a more clean way to do that. **Array** in AS3 is a lot like C# **ArrayList**, you can insert elements to either end and extract elements from either end without re-indexing elements manually:

```
        trace(3);
        // If you are sure the first element is not empty
        // you can get its reference removing them from 
        // the Array at the same time.
        removeChild(circlearray1[i].shift());
        removeChild(circlearray2[i].shift());
        trace(4);
        // All Array elements are automatically shifted
        // by -1 so you don't need to move each of them manually.
        circlearray1[i][19] = new Shape();
        circlearray2[i][19] = new Shape();
```

Comment: Arrrrgh! How did I not catch that typo? That fixed it, thank you! :D

Comment: @Dimentio Because your code is too complicated for what it does. It is not that difficult to lose your way with that condensed mass of script.